# SparkSQL custom defined function in when clause

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
id val1 val2
------------
 1  v11  v12
 2  v21  v22
 3  v31  v32
 4  v41  v42
 5  v51  v52
 6  v61  v62
```

Each row represents a person which may belong to one or more groups.I have a function that takes the values for each row, and determines whether that person meets the criteria for a particular group:

```
def isInGroup: Boolean = f(group: Int)(id: String, v1: String, v2: String)
```

and I'm trying to output a DataFrame like this:

```
Group1 Group2 Group3 Group4
---------------------------
     3      0      6      1
```

Here's my code so far, which doesn't work. Unfortunately, the when clause only takes a parameter of type `Column`, and my function doesn't work. User Defined functions don't work either. I'd really like to stick with the select/struct/as was of doing it if possible.

```
val summaryDF = dataDF
    .select(struct(
        sum(when(isInGroup(1)($"id", $"val1", $"val2"), value = 1)).as("Group1")),
        sum(when(isInGroup(2)($"id", $"val1", $"val2"), value = 1)).as("Group2")),
        sum(when(isInGroup(3)($"id", $"val1", $"val2"), value = 1)).as("Group3")),
        sum(when(isInGroup(4)($"id", $"val1", $"val2"), value = 1)).as("Group4"))
    ))
```

Comment: if you can share the inner codes of your function then I can try to help you using when condition

Answer (score 0):

As I shown in [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50297531/9613318), you'll need an `udf`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf 

def isInGroupUDF(group: Int) = udf(isInGroup(group) _)

sum(when(
  isInGroupUDF(1)($"id", $"val1", $"val2"), 1
)).as("Group1")
```

If you want to avoid listing columns you can try for example with default arguments:

```
def isInGroupUDF(group: Int, id: Column = $"id", 
                 v1: Column = $"val1", v2: Column = $"val2") = {
  val f = udf(isInGroup(group) _)
  f(id, v1, v2)
}

sum(when(
  isInGroupUDF(1), 1
)).as("Group1")
```

Comment: Can you explain what the underscore in `udf(isInGroup(1) _)` is for?

Comment: Also, is there a way so that I don't have to list out all the columns in the udf?

Comment: It means it is unapplied function.